# Orbitdb + IPFS in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ipfs, orbitdb

I am trying to use orbit-db along with the IPFS and I am going through the official documentation of OrbitDB. ATM, I am simply trying to create a db(specifically key-value store) and I have the following code uptil now

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs')
const OrbitDB = require('orbit-db')

createDb = async() => {

        try {
            const ipfsOptions = {
                config: {
                  my-config-options
                },
                EXPERIMENTAL: {
                  pubsub: true
                }
            }

            const ipfs = await IPFS.create(ipfsOptions)            
            const orbitdb = await OrbitDB.createInstance(ipfs)
            const db = await orbitdb.create('test', 'keyvalue', {
                overwrite: false,
                replicate: true,
                accessController: {
                    admin: ['*'],
                    write: ['*']
                }
            })
            console.log(db)
            await db.put('hello', { name: 'world' })
            console.log(db.all)
        } catch (error) {
            console.trace(error)

        }
    }
```

But I keep getting the same error no matter what I try

`Trace: Error: Could not append entry, key "..." is not allowed to write to the log`

So any help would be much appreciated. Also do comment if any information is missing and I would add it as per the requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a small issue with your `accessController`.
The presence of the `admin` property indicates that you want to use the `orbitdb` type like this:

```
                accessController: {
                    type: 'orbitdb',
                    admin: ['*'],
                    write: ['*']
                }
```

Otherwise if you wish to use the default `ipfs` type, remove the admin property like this:

```
                accessController: {
                    type: 'ipfs',
                    write: ['*']
                }
```

Comment: what are the main differences between the two?

Comment: It errors out to `Database '...' is type 'keyvalue' but was opened as 'ipfs'` or `Database '...' is type 'keyvalue' but was opened as 'orbitdb'`

Comment: Seems to work on sandbox io but not on my machine(Windows)

Comment: > what are the main differences between the two?
orbitdb access controller allows adding write access to other identities dynamically, ipfs type doesn't

Comment: So if I init orbitdb with ipfs type, other users wont be able to add data to the database?

Comment: The 'ipfs' type acess controller has a static list of users that can write. It's defined when you create the db. The 'orbitdb' type acess controller has the option to add write acess for users at a later time. Using a write access list of '*' means the db is witeable by anyone regardless of the access controller type